# Xamarin Forms Labs - Geolocator

Tags: xamarin.forms

How do you use the "GeoLocator" function in Xamarin Forms Labs. When i added the "GeoLocator" method in my class i kept getting the error that this.SetProperty does not exist. Anyone know how to use "GeoLocator"?

Answer (score 1):

SetProperty is only available on the very latest pre release nuget package, and it's   a method from our Base ViewModel...

You have to show your code to see what you are trying to do.

but it should be as simple as this:

```
 var geolocator = DependencyService.Get<IGeolocator>();
 var result = geolocator.GetPositionAsync(10000);
 var strLatitude = result.Latitude.ToString("N4");
 var strLongitude = result.Longitude.ToString("N4"),
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Rui's answer, I would recommend using [Plugins for Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/plugins) for this type of behavior. Specifically, the [Geolocator Plugin for Xamarin and Windows](https://blog.xamarin.com/geolocation-for-ios-android-and-windows-made-easy/).

Both of these geolocation codebases derived from Xamarin.Mobile, but as far as I can tell, the plugin is a bit more up-to-date, and supports Windows 10 (UWP) development as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you post some of the code that you are using, it will be easier to help you out. But in the meantime, `SetProperty` does not exist because you are not inheriting from the `Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Data.ObservableObject` class. It contains the `SetProperty` method which is merely an implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` (changes the property if the value is different and raises the PropertyChanged event).

So you can either inherit from the XFormsLab's `ObservableObject` (or it's base view model class which inherits from `ObservableObject`, `Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Mvvm.ViewModel`) and then you will have access to `SetProperty`. Or you can not use `SetProperty` at all and use your own implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Answer (score 0):

We took the code from this library and cleaned it up. You can clone the repo here:

https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Adapt.Presentation.git

It is complete with samples for each platform. If you run the sample, you will see a tab for GeoLocator and it should run on all platforms. Android and UWP have been tested thoroughly.

The NuGet package Adapt.Presentation works to some extent but I've had difficulty getting it to work correctly on all platforms.